# Counting unique values in all table columns

Tags: sql

What would be the most efficient SQLish way of compiling a list of unique values, with record counts for each unique value, for all of the columns in a table?

How would one differentiate columns with repeated values (such as country or state codes) versus columns that contain names and addresses - in which case there would be too many variations?

Comment: With SQL questions you should always mention which DBMS you are using.

Comment: I don't understand your question, rewrite it please so we can help.
Guys, don't be aggressive to newbie site members questions giving them negative voting for their questions when it's not clear enough, rather than guide them to how to describe their issues clearly.

Comment: Think of Excel and how its column filtering gives you a list of all of the values in a column, complete with record counts for each value.  Is that not what I asked ;?)  I am looking for a more generic SQL approach as opposed to using some DB specific utility. ... The second part of my question deals with "too many unique values" in columns, such that one ends up doing this for "coded" fields such as country or state codes - which is what I already said. ;)

Answer (score 1):

For any single column, you can do:

```
SELECT column, COUNT(*) AS column_count
  FROM tablename
 GROUP BY column
 ORDER BY column
```

There isn't a simple way to do this for all columns in a single statement; you end up with the most awful multiple outer join with ordering problems and all sorts of issues to resolve.  (Each separate column can have a different number of distinct values, for example.)

The second half of your question ('how would one differentiate') is inscrutable; you have to know your data set to make that differentiation.

Comment: "closed as not a real question by Mitch Wheat, balexandre, dasblinkenlight, Brian Roach, bensiu Dec 29 '12 at 2:45" ... ... Please read again my question and then Johnathan's perfect answer and then consider the following.  Your attitude and all those minuses is totally pathetic because if one knows 2/3 of subject matter in order to frame the question perfectly then there is no need to ask because one knows enough to figure out the remaining 1/3.  Jonathan understood what you could not.